# WiFi connectivity issues on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04, realtek-wireless

My WiFi is refusing to identify available networks, it disconnects at will and refuses to establish back connections. After restarting or switching it off to switch it on, it might come up without WiFi function entirely or work well and resume with the issues.
I have tried so far; switching off the connectivity checking under privacy, setting WiFi connection power save to 2, i ran a script to the network issues, here is result of the script
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XpYtCVKcsP/

Comment: Try changing the value in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` from 3 to 2. It is the power save mode, I had a similar problem and I solved in this way...

Comment: @Dresult, I did that too, it's set to 2, it still didn't solve the issue

Comment: @ArturMienild, thank you for editing the question better

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: @waltinator, after doing that, what should I do please

Comment: Read the resulting messages carefully to understand what it's telling you about your system's events. If you cannot, [edit] your Question and add some information, properly formatted. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: @waltinator, Alright, thank you sir